# Hibernate criteria using and/or together

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I need to write a hibernate criteria for this SQL:

```
select distinct USER_ID from USER_ROLE  
where USER_TERM_DT is null 
and ((ROLE_ID in (101,102) 
and STATE_ID in ('MD')) or ROLE_ID = 150)
```

The **role_ids** will have a combination of values (101,102,150,151)
The OR part only needs to be there if the Role_Id is 150 or 151.

The **USER_ROLE** table has **Role_id** & **state_id**. Only roles 101 & 102 are associated with state_ids.

If all the 4 role_id values are there, the SQL would be like:

```
select distinct USER_ID from USER_ROLE  
where USER_TERM_DT is null 
and ((ROLE_ID in (101,102) 
and STATE_ID in ('MD')) or ROLE_ID in (150,151))
```

Please help in this matter. I'm reading I need to use conjunction & disjunction together, but just not able to come up with the right code. Hope it's clear & my SQL is right.

Comment: Can you show your attempts at using conjunction and disjunction?

Comment: It looks similar to the sample code below. Do you want me to put the actual code that I got to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work - replace the 'is null' and the 'in' expressions with the corresponding Restrictions

```
criteria.conjuction()
        .add(USER_TERM_DT is null )
        .add(criteria.disjuction().
                 add(
                   criteria.conjuction()
                            .add(ROLE_ID in (101,102) )
                            .add(STATE_ID in ('MD'))
                 )
                 .add(ROLE_ID in (150,151))
         )
```

Comment: Thanks Kamal. It works! but the SQL shows something like this:

Comment: select distinct USER_ID from USER_ROLE where SER_TERM_DT is null and (((ROLE_ID in (?, ?, ?) and STATE_ID in (?)) or ROLE_ID in (?)))

Comment: Is there anyway to remove all these extra brackets or is that ok? Thanks so much again!

Comment: Not sure, extra brackets usually don't make a difference. Are you getting wrong results or the execution plan is different?  Can you please accept the answer,if

Comment: No. I'm getting the right results but it is annoying to see those extra brackets & looks like I'm missing something.